# open port on IBM Container after installation

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have deployed IBM Bluemix container with a dockerfile.
In this dockerfile Expose one port. say port 22.

Is it possible to open another port without deploying to a new container.
So is it possible to open another port on the already deployed container. say port 2812.

Answer (score 0):

docker containers ports on Bluemix can be managed during container building and during the run command. Moreover I suggest you to use the option -p if you are using "cf ic" or "docker" or "ice" client from command line with the same ports listed in dockerfile expose setting.
Once a container is started you cannot add another port "on the fly"

Comment: If I run the following command: `cf ic run -p 2812 --name <source_container_name> registry.eg-bg.bluemix.net/<namespace>/<source_container_image_name>` 

I get the following error:  `Error response from daemon: "IC0005: container with the same name already exists"
FAILED`

Comment: Run cf ic ps -a to check if there is already present a container running with the same name

Comment: This is correct. But I want open a extra port on already running container.
Is this possible?

Comment: As already described in my response, once a container is started you cannot add another port "on the fly".
You should stop the container and restart it with the added port: the docker/Bluemix environment needs to be configured with the new routing policies, and it cannot be done on the fly